# CosmosDB not returning the type on read

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working on an express session for Cosmos, and I get a problem, I'm typing the read to return a Session interface, but I get another object, not my.

```
type Session = {
  cookie?: string;
};
```

```
get(
  sid: string,
  callback: (err: any, session?: session.SessionData) => void,
): void {
  this.container
    .item(this._buildKey(sid), this.partitionKey)
    .read<Session>()
    .then((response) => {
       // HERE, I want to use the return value from `read`, but response does not contains Session properties
    })
    .catch((error) => callback(error));
}
```

I get an `ItemResponse<Session>` on response, but I cannot extract the property `cookie`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you see when you do console.log(response)

Comment: I haven't run the code yet @Sajeetharan, let give a try

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I need to access the property `resource`

```
response.resource.cookie
```